# Selecting all rows where part of a row value is like another value in same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, but figured I'd ask. In Microsoft SQL Server, I'm trying to scan an entire column to display all row values that are like another row value in the same column.

Is there a system function or system stored procedure to do this?

Here is an example of the data in the column:

```
Test Deal for Asset MGMT
Test PI
Test PI; Test PI e
```

All of these rows would be displayed by the query because they all have "Test" in the row value. But, "Test" is not necessarily the word we are looking for.

Essentially:

```
select columnname 
from tablename    
where columnname in/like (%ColumnNames%) and count(%rowvalue%) > 1.
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why "Test" and not another word? Or any word will do if it shows more than once in the column?

Comment: What constitutes "like"? Is it `like` where one value is contained in another, e.g. `'Vogon'` is in `'A Vogon poetry slam!'`, or is it something fuzzy in common, e.g. `'We are the world.'` and `'They are the world famous trio.'`? Or perhaps `'World peace.'` and `'Whirled peas.'`? The first is easy enough to handle with a self join: `select Pattern.ColumnName, Match.ColumnName from YerTable as Pattern left outer join YerTable as Match on Pattern.Id != Match.Id and Match.ColumnName like '%' + Pattern.ColumnName + '%';`. Perhaps with checks for empty strings.

Comment: @TheImpaler, thank you for the help.  Any word will do if it shows more than once in the row values for the single column.

Comment: @HABO, thank you for the help.  The first scenario is what I'm looking for.  I'm not looking for something like World Peace and Whirled Peas (but I did laugh at your creativity).  Could you help me with the Pattern ID and March ID?  I'm not sure I follow this part of the logic.  Oh wait, I do follow.  My apologies.  Thank you.  Let me try this.

Comment: I've assumed that the table has an `Id` column that uniquely identifies rows. The query gives you all of the rows in the table (`left outer join`) and matches them with any _other_ row (`Pattern.Id != Match.Id`, i.e. a row is never compared to itself because it would always match) for _likeness_ (`Match.ColumnName like '%' + Pattern.ColumnName + '%'`). The `outer join` ensures that rows with no matches are still output. Better?

Comment: @HABO, Thank you. This is very close! When I run this, the pattern.column returns "Test PI" and the Matched.Column returns "Test PI; Test PI e". However, the other value above is not showing: "Test Deal for Asset MGMT".

Comment: Using [`like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this way is only going to provide _all or nothing_ matches. You could split each column at spaces into tokens, e.g. `'Test'`, `'Deal'`, `'for'` ..., and then start a new game of matching. `'Test Deal for Asset MGMT'` and `'Test PI'` would yield five and two tokens. Is one in common good enough to match? If more than one matches is the order significant, e.g. `'Foo Bar Buzz'` vs. `'Foo Buzz'` vs. `'Buzz Bar'`? Does two matches in order beat two out of order?

Comment: Hi @HABO, thank you again for your continued help!  I'm curious how I would do the above?  One word in common is good enough to match, but if two words match, in order, that would be more significant for sure.  I really appreciate you helping.  Thank you.

Comment: If you care about order you can't use [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Start [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/splitting-strings-sql-server-2016-rescue/) to find a suitable string splitter that returns the tokens in order with an `ItemNumber`. There are also some examples of using `cross apply` to split columns. (Using a Common Table Expression (CTE) may make it easier to keep track of the steps.) ...

Comment: ... The split results need to be joined together to produce a set of matching tokens and their indexes. You can then count matches and compare orders between them. I'll leave it to you to start work on it and, if it doesn't fall together, post an appropriate question about specific problems. Aside: Splitting on blanks still leaves dangling bits of punctuation, e.g. `'Who''s'`, `'on'`, `'first?'`, that may provide additional challenges since `'First'` and `'first?'` won't match.

Comment: @HABO, thank you so much.  I think this is going to get me to my desired result.  Is there a way for me to mark your answer correct if its in the comments here?

Comment: Since I only commented, but didn't post an answer, you can't add to my account of quatloos (or whatever they pay here). Thanks for thinking of it and perhaps we'll meet again.

Comment: @HABO, thank you so much for your help.  If you'd like to post it below, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: You've already thanked me. That'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the `like` pattern from rows:

```
where col2 like '%' + col1 + '%'
```